# List most recents files used

Tags: 7, views, paragraphs

We have a **Documents** bundle which is a list of documents, and an **Accordeon** which includes the previous one.

```
NODE_PAGE
|
|--- DOCUMENTS
|
|--- ACCORDEON
|    |
|    |--- DOCUMENTS
```

With this choice, I can attach documents directly to the node or to *Accordeon* sub-elements.

How can I list the most recent documents in a view? (I have to mix file_managed directly linked to the node and file_managed linked to the paragraph which is linked to the node.)

Is it possible from the view setting, or do I have to alter the query with `hook_views_query_alter()`?

Comment: I take you mean that the second content type has an entity reference field that references nodes of the first content type. In Drupal, a content type cannot contain another content type.

Comment: @kiamlaluno : I am using "paragraphs" so DOCUMENTS is a paragraph, and ACCORDEON is also one.

And my problem is I don't know how to access to a paragraph that is in a paragraph using Views .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I choose to create a View of type File and to alter data with the `hook_views_pre_render()`. I can now do queries and other custom treatments and set the results data of my view.